# Javascript: How to push multiple image files into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple input files

```
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_0">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_1">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_2">
```

I want each of it store in array so i did, this is working to me

```
var imageContainer = [];
var file_name = document.getElementsByName('file_name[]');
for(var i = 0; i< file_name.length; i++){
    alert(i);
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file_id_'+i);
    imageContainer.push(fileUpload.files[0]);
}

var data = new FormData();
for(var b=0; b<imageContainer.length; b++){
    data.append('file_name[]', imageContainer[b]);
}
```

But if one of the input file is empty is I got an error Cannot read property 'files' of null.

So I am trying to push the files in other way but not working

```
var file_nameArr = [];
$('input[name="file_name[]"]').each(function(k,v){
    file_nameArr.push($(v).val()); //How do i push each files into my array?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if one of the input file is empty is I got an error Cannot read property 'files' of null.

That doesn't mean the `input` is empty, it means your `getElementById` call didn't return an element at all.

There's no reason for that `getElementById` call, you **already** have the elements in the collection referenced by your `file_name` variable. Just use it, and check its `length` to make sure it does have at least one file in it:

```
var imageContainer = [];
var file_name = document.getElementsByName('file_name[]');
for(var i = 0; i< file_name.length; i++){
    alert(i);
    var fileUpload = file_name[i];                    // ***
    if (fileUpload.files.length) {                    // ***
        imageContainer.push(fileUpload.files[0]);
    }                                                 // ***
}
```

Note that the filenames will have fake paths on them.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if `fileUpload` is not null..to do that add a condition in your for loop as pointed below:

```
var file_name = document.getElementsByName('file_name[]');
for(var i = 0; i< file_name.length; i++){
    alert(i);
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file_id_'+i);
  if(fileUpload )
    imageContainer.push(fileUpload.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*v* is your element, so *$(v)* is nonse, please have a look at the example.

```js
var file_nameArr = [];
$('input[name="file_name[]"]').each(function(k,v){
  if (v.value.length > 0)
    file_nameArr.push(v.value); //How do i push the files into my array?
  else
    console.log('input is empty')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_0">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_1">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_2">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_3">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_4">
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" id="file_id_5">
```